# Use hyperlink for the text shown when no data is available

Tags: reporting-services, vbscript

Long story short, I want show "Please Click HERE" ("HERE" should be a hyperlink that points to www.google.com) when there is no data populated for a specific table.

So when there is no data, I want to show "Please Click Here" and the word "Here" should be a hyperlink that a user can click on and get to www.google.com

I can't use "point to URL" in this kind of situation. I can use an expression, but I need to figure out what my `="expression"` should be to enable hyperlink?

**Update:** I have a table that gets populated with data based on users. If our database has no data for a user, that user sees empty page. I would like to use NoRowsMessage property of the SSRS and enforce that on that table. And I can either write text directly or write an expression. I need to know how to enable hyperlink in that text? If I write "please visit www.google.com", the "www.google.com" does not become a hyperlink when I view the report, it's just plain text I want that url to be a hyperlink so user can click on it and it brings them to www.google.com page.

Comment: i think its better if you leave the long story long :) you have to expand, maybe a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do this. One workaround would be to have a textbox with URL action right on top of the table, and toggle visibility for both so only the applicable control is visible.